# Unable to create SharePoint online list items using Power shell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, csom

I want to add list items inside a SharePoint online list, so i run this command:-

```
 $SiteUrl = "https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/t"
 $ListName= "Child2"
 Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteUrl -UseWebLogin
 $Ctx = Get-PnPContext
    
 #Get the list Item
 $List=$Ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
    
 $Import = Import-Csv -Path "C:\CSV\finaldelta3.csv"
    
 for ($counter=0; $counter -lt $Import.Length; $counter++){
    
 $ListItemInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation
 $ListItem = $List.AddItem($ListItemInfo)
    
 #Set Column Values
 $ListItem["Title"] = "Hello World!"
    
 #Apply changes to list
 $ListItem.Update()
 $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
 }
```

now on one tenant, i will not get any error, but the list item will not get created, while on another tenant i got this exception and also the item will not get created as well:-

> Cannot convert argument "parameters", with value:
> "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation", for
> "AddItem" to type
> "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation": "Cannot
> convert the  "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation"
> value of type
> "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation" to type
> "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation"."  At line:4
> char:1  + $ListItem = $List.AddItem($ListItemInfo)  +
>
> ```
>      + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
>       Cannot index into a null array.  At line:7 char:1  + $ListItem["Title"] = "Hello World!"#$Import[$counter].'Caller Info' #
> ...  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
>       You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.  At line:10 char:1  + $ListItem.Update()  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
> ```

so any idea what is going on?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried updating your SPO Management Shell:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35588

And/or the SPO Client Component SDK:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038

I'm not sure if it is required by PnPOnline, but with SPOServices you need to load the assembly as well:

```
    Add-Type -Path "$Env:ProgramFiles\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$Env:ProgramFiles\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$Env:ProgramFiles\SharePoint Client Components\16.0\Assemblies\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant.dll"
```

Or alternatively:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant") | Out-Null
```

Personally, I start my script with

```
#Requires -Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell
```